# Is there a way to customize the stackoverflow/stackexchange flair?

Tags: support

The options on displaying flair are good but it might not suitable for all templates.

I tried the ways mentioned in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/how-to-change-flair-default-themes-background-color) question but it does not work for stackexhange.

Any techniques to modify the flair output or may be create your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no server-side options to modify the flair besides the specified themes. The methods in the linked answer don't work anymore because the flair is just a graphic now (back then it was a webpage you embedded directly or generated with Javascript)

You can certainly create your own though; the information is available through the [API](https://stackapps.com/). One app already does this, [StackFlair](http://www.stackflair.com/), although it appears to be broken at the moment

Comment: So, StackFlair is not working, so how to create such app.

Comment: @Starx It actually seems to [work now](http://www.stackflair.com/Generate/31759f60-0536-4343-a728-045a4e217082.png), but it working or not doesn't really matter. Check out the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), or the [StackFlair source code](https://github.com/rchern/StackFlair)